# Кроссбраузерная обработка событий

Tags: ооп, события, javascript, firefox

Приветствую. Решил реализовать галерейку на JS но столкнулся с проблемой.

```
var gallery = function() {};
gallery.prototype = {
nav_prev : document.createElement('td'),
next : function(e){
console.log(this);
if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
// if (!this.initialized) return;
if (this.index < 0) return;
if (this.index == this.size - 1) {
    this.index = 0;
}
else {
    this.index++;
}
this.change();
},
init : function(){
    this.nav_prev.id = 'gallery_nav_prev';
this.nav_prev.addEventListener('click',this.prev,false);
this.nav_prev.innerHTML = '<';
}
}
```

Пришлось сделать так, чтобы событие отрабатывалось в FF. Но теперь, я не знаю как передать в метод ссылку на объект, чтобы вызвать из него метод change(). Кто нибудь, подскажите, как передать ссылку на объект?

*Обновление*

http://jsfiddle.net/VLGcr/4/ вот фиддл. В мозилле сработает только черная кнопка, но как в ней получить ссылку на объект gal - я не пойму. Красная отлично всё отрабатывает, но не работает в мозилле, так как window.event is undefined.

Comment: На какой объект ссылку передавать надо? По идее у вас все работает, если нет - делайте jsfiddle и показывайте что не работает.

Comment: @Bet если у вас там jQuery зачем все эти document.createElement , addEventListener ??

Comment: Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) поможет. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Rpx6A/2/).

```
document.getElementById('gallery_btn2').onclick = this.prev.bind( this);
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@Bet](/users/20003/bet)](/users/20003/bet) так а что мешает e  протащить через все callback ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/6/

насчет передать контекст, кроссбраузерно будет [apply](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/8/) например. или [call](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/9/)

Comment: Что-то не так. В FF, во всяком случае, [пример с apply](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/8/), равно как и [пример с call](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/9/) пихают в контекст this DOM элемент, по которому кликнули, а не объект галереи.

Comment: ну так для того и apply, если его не делать, то в контексте будет this самого объекта. непонятно в чем тогда проблема.

Comment: вышеупомянутый bind можно реализовать вот так

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VLGcr/11/